# Submitting forms as a Collection Using the <logic:iterate> tag in Struts1.3

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags

Using Struts 1.3.

Submitting forms as a collection using the `<logic:iterate>` tag I'd like to format multiple records of user to edit values.

When the data is submitted back to the `Action` how can it handle a list of form in an Action form? Is there a way to submit the results as a collection of forms?

For example, I have `List<EmployeeForm>` and I am iterating these records on my jsp page and it's working fine. But the records are editable on the JSP page, so after modifying the records and pressing the submit button I need the `List<EmployeeForm>` with updated records inside my action class to update the records inside the DB.

update, my jsp page is below given:

```
<html:form action="modify.do" styleId="LogicIterateForm" method="post">
            <table style="font-weight:bold">
            <tr><td>Employee ID</td><td>Employee Name</td></tr>
            <logic:iterate id="employee" name="LogicIterateForm" property="emp" indexId="i">

           <tr>
```

`enter code here`

```
           </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
<tr>
    <html:submit onclick="submitForm()">Modify</html:submit>
</tr>
    </table>
        </html:form>
```

action: to perform on clicking of  `Modify` button

```
LogicIterateForm logicIterateForm=(LogicIterateForm)form;
        List<Employee> empList=logicIterateForm.getEmp();
        System.out.println("Size of emp:::::"+empList.size());
        if(empList!=null && empList.size()>0)
        {
            for(Employee emp:empList)
            {
                if(emp!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("EmployeeID:::::::::::"+emp.getEmpId());
                    System.out.println("EmployeeName:::::::::::"+emp.getEmpName());
                }
            }
        }
```

and it is working fine to send the list of employees inside the action but unfortunately i am unable to get the updated form fields value inside my action. please help me where i am doing mistake.

and below is my ActionForm

```
public class LogicIterateForm extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {


    private List<Employee> emp=new ArrayList<Employee>();


    public List<Employee> getEmp() {
        return emp;
    }

    public void setEmp(List<Employee> emp) {
        this.emp = emp;
    }
```

and Employee class is a plan java class with `setter and getter of empId and empName`

Comment: There are a number of ways to approach this, but the easiest is to use array notation in the form properties, like "employees[1].name" etc. You'd also need to have a hidden field with the employee id.

Comment: Thanks Dave, But I am unable to achieve this could please give me any example please It's very needful for me.

Comment: [Start here](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.5/struts-taglib/indexedprops.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try, If I am facing any problem i will let you know.

Comment: Dave, I am able to send the list of employees inside my action, but unfortunately i am doing some where something wrong, Because i am not getting the updated value of form fields, it's gives me only the already existence fields value. i am posting my jsp page please see it.

Comment: What's the action form look like?

Comment: The Jsp page which is showing the list of employees details has a action (modify.do).
and i want to submit the list on clicking of Modify button.
through action, and able to submit the list of employees on clicking of Modify button but, Not able to get the update Form property, for example it's showing employee name as subodh, and i want to modify it as Dave, but it can't take updated record inside the action class.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Please show the definition of your ActionForm.

Comment: and Employee class is simple java class with setter getter of empId and empName fields

Comment: Please put that in the question, not the comments.

Comment: Also, unless strictly for historical reasons or because your boss is making you, don't learn Struts 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's working fine now, Once again Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad you worked it out :)

Comment: Please after adding a boolean filed as:<td><html:checkbox name="emp" value="${emp.isCheck}" property="isCheck" styleId="isCheck" indexed="true"/></td>

Comment: Not getting update value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nutshell version is that the generated HTML will have an incorrect `name` attribute. The `ActionForm` list property is named `emp` but you're calling it `employee`.

The longer version includes some other miscellaneous stuff that should make things a little easier for you in the long run.

First, here's the `Action` I used to display the form. Note that I am not putting anything into scope explicitly--the framework does this for us. It appears as though you're explicitly setting a form into scope for use by `<logic:iterator>`, but that's redundant.

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    Employee emp1 = new Employee("1", "Dave");
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("2", "Subodh");
    ((LogicIterateForm) form).setEmp(Arrays.asList(emp1, emp2));
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

Second, the JSP page can be made simpler because of the above. Note that the name of the input element must match the name in the form, `emp`, otherwise Struts won't know what to do with the input value, and it will be ignored.

```
<logic:iterate name="empForm" property="emp" id="emp">
  <tr>
    <td><html:text name="emp" value="${emp.empId}" property="empId" indexed="true"/></td>
    <td><html:text name="emp" value="${emp.empName}" property="empName" indexed="true"/></td>
  </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Then inside the action that's being submitted to all the data will be in the form as expected.

```
List<Employee> emps = ((LogicIterateForm) form).getEmp();
for (Employee emp : emps) {
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", emp.getEmpId(), emp.getEmpName());
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Dave, In case of boolean field it i am not getting update value. please see update question.

Comment: I came across the BeanUtils.populate exception in my case and solved it reading these docs: https://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsCatalogLazyList
Just in case someone have this problem too.